# Compact connected in $\mathbb R$

Tags: general-topology

I want to prove that if $K$ is compact connected subset of $\mathbb R$, there exists  $a,b\in \mathbb R$ such that $K=[a,b]$

Comment: I'd like to help you but you are suppose to show some effort first.

Comment: See my answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/562329/prove-that-a-b-is-connected-space/562388#562388

Answer (score 3):

Some hints:

If a subset $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ is connected, and $x,y \in A$, then $[x,y] \subset A$. To see this, suppose for some $z \in (x,y)$ that $z \notin A$. Then $A \subset (-\infty,z) \cup (z,\infty)$, which contradicts the fact that $A$ is connected.

If $K$ is compact, then $\inf K, \sup K \in K$.

The final details:

> Hence we have $K \subset [\inf K, \sup K]$. Since $K$ is connected, the above result shows that $[\inf K, \sup K] \subset K$. Hence $K = [\inf K, \sup K]$, as required.

Answer (score 2):

Every connected subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ must be an interval and any compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is limited and closed. Thus, every compact connected subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ must be a limited closed interval, as desired.