# Compact and Connected.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I have a proof which needs to check by other person.

Show: Every nonempty compact connected set in R is of the form [a, b].

My proof:

Let's take any nonempty set D in R so there exist a, b, z in D and let a < z < b.
By definition of nonempty set, D can be an interval since a, b in D and a < z < b. And also this set is connected by hypothesis.

Since D is compact by hypothesis, D should be closed and bounded by Heine-Borel theorem.
Hence D = [a, b]

Any comment, arrangement would be very appreciated it!

Comment: What are the connected subsets of $\Bbb R$?  They're just the intervals (of any type, finite or infinite).  What are some properties compact sets have?  They are closed and bounded.  So what intervals are closed and bounded?

Comment: You really want to say any nonempty compact connected set $D$. Be explicit in what you are using. Then why do there exist $3$ points? It is true but it being nonempty one gives you $1$ point. Why do you get three (think about it). Moreover, it can 'being' an interval doesn't make it one--this is what you're trying to show! Really your using the Heine-Borel Theorem should come first to make things easy for you, not last.

Comment: Singletons are also compact and connected.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/563532/compact-connected-in-mathbb-r

Comment: This is the second repetition of the same question within 20 mins. or so. What are the chances...

Answer (score 3):

Let $E\subset\mathbb{R}$ be nonempty, connected and compact. If $E$ is the singleton set, then it's of the form [x,x] for $x\in E$. If $E$ is not the singleton set, then since $E$ is nonempty and connected, it must be some type of interval. Since $E$ is compact, it is also closed and bounded. Since $E$ is closed it contains all it's limit points and thus must contain the end points of the interval.